# Chrome: Force browser refesh?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Developing a Chrome Extension... I'm wondering, can I force the users browser to refresh the current page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a background page:

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(function(tab){
    chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: tab.url});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not. If you describe why you need them to refresh perhaps you can find the desired behavior some other way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, via Javascript (here's an example with a countdown shown on the screen):

```
var targetURL="http://www.wherever.com/about.php" /* or use about.php */
var countdownfrom=10
var currentsecond=document.redirect.redirect2.value=countdownfrom+1 
function countredirect(){ 
if (currentsecond!=1){ 
currentsecond-=1 
document.redirect.redirect2.value=currentsecond 
} 
else{ 
window.location=targetURL 
return 
} 
setTimeout("countredirect()",1000) 
}
```